# Sync VS 2019 with Github after branch merging

Tags: github

I have created project in Visual studio 2019 connect it with Github and made one branch called client-dev in VS2019 developed some time committed to that branch . When i was done i created pull request in VS2019  and went to github and merge the branches. Now i have a problem because in VS2019 my default branch is client-dev not master and i dont know how to sync state of my github project. If i change the branch from client-dev to master i get older project state. I tried in Visual studio merge the branches but didnt go through so i dont mess up github repo .

I am aware that i can pull whole project in new folder on my drive...

Comment: If you performed the merge from github, you'll want to switch to the master branch in your local repository and then perform a pull to fast forward your working branch to the new remote commit.
If you've committed new code to your local repository since the remote merge then you may want to stash your changes before pulling.

Comment: On Team Explorer i clicked Sync then Pull , and my local repo is up to date and everything works. Thanks ! Pull = Fetch + Merge

Comment: I've moved my comment into an answer, since it seems to have answered your question. If that's the case, please consider accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you performed the merge from github, you'll want to switch to the master branch in your local repository and then perform a pull to fast forward your working branch to the new remote commit. 
If you've committed new code to your local repository since the remote merge then you may want to stash your changes before pulling.